# Hiding button if swift Coredata function is blank

Tags: swift

I have a problem with some code. I have a function called attachments. It calls on a DatabaseManager to a specific function getttachmentdata. This calls on coredata to see if a user has uploaded an image and call on it. If it has it I have another part of the code where the user clicks on a button and it shows that image.

The problem is that when the data is blank or there is nothing uploaded I wanted the button to be disabled. This might be a simple fix but I am not quite sure actually.

```
    let attachments = DataBaseManager().getAttachmentData()
    if attachments.isEmpty  {
        btnProofOfDelivery.isHidden = true
        btnProofOfDelivery.isEnabled = false
    }
```

I wrote the code above, however, when I tried running my program it still displayed the button that I wanted to disappear. Running without the if statement makes the button disappear.

code for getattachments

```
func getAttachmentData()-> Array<Data>{
    var data1 = [Data]()
    let context = CoreData.sharedCoreData.managedObjectContext
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Attachments")

    do {
        let result = try context.fetch(request)
        print(result)
        for data in result as! [NSManagedObject] {
            print(data.value(forKey: "attachment") as! Data)
            data1.append(data.value(forKey: "attachment") as! Data)
        }
        if data1.count == 0 {
            return [Data()]
        }else{
            return data1
        }
    } catch {
        return [Data()]
    }
}
```

Comment: Print attachments array and check whether the data is blank

Comment: I will do that right now.

Comment: I did not get any data from the function.

Comment: Can you show us the code for `getAttachmentData`?

Comment: OK I added it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is your bug, if the fetch doesn't return anything you return a new `Data` object

```
if data1.count == 0 {
   return [Data()]
}
```

You of course meant to write

```
if data1.count == 0 {
   return [Data]()
}
```

and some issue in catch

or you can just remove all of that since `data1` is properly initialised so you can just return it either way so the code after the `for {}` loop can then be reduced to

```
        return data1
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Thats where the problem was!